# Equivalent of Akka but for .NET (Concurrency Framework)

Tags: .net, frameworks, concurrency, akka

Is there something equivalent of [Akka](http://akka.io/) but for .NET?

http://doc.akka.io/use-cases

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may take a look at https://github.com/phatboyg/Stact
It falls into the 'something equivalent' category.

Answer (score 9):

This is an (/my) ongoing port of Akka actors for .NET 
[EDIT]
The project have evolved into a direct port of real Akka: https://github.com/akkadotnet

It is in large a class by class, line by line port.

Comment: @user310291 you should definitely set this as an answer for now